# Finding the positions of the max element in a numpy array if there are more than one

Tags: python, numpy

Just wondering how to find the index of where the maximums are if there are more than one of them?

At the moment i was doing:

```
max = np.amax(V)
position = V.tolist().index(max)
```

But say we have V = [0,1,2,5,2,5,3]
We will get
max = 5
position = 3 (but not 5?)

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to find indices which are equal to maximum value:

```
>>> a
array([2, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0, 5, 1, 4, 1])
>>> np.nonzero(a == a.max())[0]
array([ 1, 10, 16])
>>> a[_]
array([5, 5, 5])
```